# how to deserialize network data into different primitives?

Tags: c++, sockets, networking

I'm sure this is a very common operation when doing any kind of network programming (or I/O with files) but I can't find the answer.

Basically I have a datagram packet coming in down the network which has a series of single precision floating point numbers (4 bytes each).

I have written some basic networking code which reads from a socket and stores the data into a buffer which is declared as follows:

```
char buffer[24];
```

This is my deserialization code:

```
for (int i=0; i<6; i++) {
    float *pf = reinterpret_cast<float*>(buffer + i*sizeof(float));
    printf("%f\n", *pf);
}
```

but it causes my program to crash.

If someone could point me to a good tutorial on this type of thing i.e. managing, storing and interpreting data, I'd really appreciate it! I've looked but I don't know what to search for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If they are *really* sending floats -- which I wouldn't recommend, if you have a choice -- then you have to do some bit hackery.

Here is a utility library I wrote to do just this kind of thing.  It works on Windows (MSVC) and Linux (GCC).  It might not work on other platforms!  Use at your own risk.

```
/**************  UTILITY ******************************/
template<class Val> Val ntohx(const Val& in)
{
    char out[sizeof(in)] = {0};
    for( size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(Val); ++i )
        out[i] = ((char*)&in)[sizeof(Val)-i-1];
    return *(reinterpret_cast<Val*>(out));
}

template<> uint16_t ntohx<uint16_t>(const uint16_t & v)
{
    return ntohs(v);
}

template<> uint32_t ntohx<uint32_t>(const uint32_t & v)
{
    return ntohl(v);
}

template<> uint64_t ntohx<uint64_t>(const uint64_t & v)
{
    uint32_t ret [] =
    {
        ntohl(((const uint32_t*)&v)[1]),
        ntohl(((const uint32_t*)&v)[0])
    };
    return *((uint64_t*)&ret[0]);
}
template<> float ntohx<float>(const float& v)
{
    uint32_t const* cast = reinterpret_cast<uint32_t const*>(&v);
    uint32_t ret = ntohx(*cast);
    return *(reinterpret_cast<float*>(&ret));
}

template<class Val> bool ieee_isnan(const Val& val)
{
    // According to the IEEE Standard for floating-point numbers, 
    // NaNs have the interesting attribute of always returning
    // false in comparisons; even to themselves.
    // All platforms we currently support use IEEE floating points,
    // so this should work. [Dib]
    return val != val;
};
```

Comment: thx I'll have a closer look at this tomorrow, have to run, just a quick question, what's wrong with sending floats?

Comment: Precision and rounding errors get all jacked up when you try to move float data from machine to machine.  A better solution is to use some form of scaled decimals.  An `__int32` for the exponent and an `__int64` for the mantissa for example, where the value is `mant * 10^exp`

Comment: Would this make a difference when sending between processes running on the same machine? Also, how do you know this, i.e. where can I find out more about this?

Comment: The `ntoh` functions correct for endian differences between architectures.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness

Comment: If the processes are all on the same machine, there is may not be any difference in endianness.  It depends on the sending application & how it was written.

Comment: Re: how I know this.  Honesytly, it's mostly experience.  But you have to start somewhere, and this is a good place to start: http://tangentsoft.net/wskfaq/

Comment: Also, check out this book:http://www.amazon.com/TCP-IP-Illustrated-3-Set/dp/0201776316/ref=sr_1_15?ie=UTF8&qid=1289962484&sr=8-15

Comment: Hey, I've decided against sending floats across the network because of its hardware dependent representation. I'm just scaling my floats into 16 bit signed integers at the sender end, and doing the reverse on the receiving end. This way I'm just sending 2's complement over the network so it should make the code more portable. Thx for the link!

Answer (score 1):

You have a buffer of 24 bytes but you operate on `24 * sizeof(float)` bytes which is quite a few more.

```
char buffer[24 * sizeof(float)];
```

Comment: you are right, I rewrote the code slightly to use constants for the array sizing and for loop, but I made a mistake. It's fixed now

Answer (score 0):

See *ntohs()* and friends.

Comment: No version for float afaik.  But yes, a more general system would need a representation-independent protocol rather than `reinterpret_cast<float>`

Comment: That is only useful for integers. Is there some extra functions that will convert floating data into a binary representation for agnostic storage and transport?